# LINQ 2 Entities SubQuery with Except (not in) and condition

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have this Database Structure

```
EVENT
--- EVENTID (PK)

EVENTSEMINAR
--- EVENTID (PFK)
--- SEMINARID (PFK)

SEMINAR
--- SEMINARID (PK)

SEMINARCLASS
--- SEMINARID (PFK)
--- CLASSID. (PK)
--- Date
```

I want to get a list of all seminars (including their Classes) that are not linked to an event, and occur after a certain date.

```
Select * 
from Seminar, SeminarClass 
Where (Seminar.SeminarId not in (select SeminarId 
                                 from EventSeminar) 
       and seminar.SeminarId = SeminarClass.SemianrId 
       and SeminarClass.Date > something);
```

How can I translate this to LINQ 2 Entities ?

(there is no such entity as EventSeminar, as it's only a navigation property)

trying to achive this with a few queries caused me some trouble as I can't use one's result as parameter to expect on the 2nd.. need some conversion that I don't know how to achieve:

```
var Seminars = from e in context.Event
                                .Include("Seminar")
                                .Where(x=>x.Seminar != null) 
               select e.Seminar;

var SC = from c in context.Seminar.Except(Seminars) select c;
```

Need some help...

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from s in context.Seminars
        where s.Date > something
              && (!s.Events.Any())
        select s;
```

You don't show the navigation property in `Seminar` for the navigation through `EventSeminar` to `Event`, so substitute it in the above if I've guessed wrong.

Comment: SeminarClass has the date, but otherwise you pointed to the right direction - s.Event.Any() (I used count == 0).

Comment: The cardinality of SeminarClass wasn't clear from your question. Do you have an answer now, or do you need help with that. If so, what is the cardinality of `Seminar -> SeminarClass` ?